# Don't indent the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, indentation

How can I prevent the items in the  bibliography from being automatically moved approximatively 1 cm to the right?

If I use `\bibitem[label]{...}` they are nicely aligned with the rest of the text, but if I just use `\bibitem{...}`, so that they get automatically numbered (which is what I want) they are moved to the right, like I explained above.

Example:

[image]

I want the automatic numbering of the first lines, but the indentation behavior of the last.

The Code that creates the above output:

```
% Created with LyX
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[unicode=true,
 bookmarks=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{enumitem}       % customizable list environments
\newlength{\lyxlabelwidth}      % auxiliary length 

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{References}
\bibitem{key-1} these lines are what happens when I only use                 \textbackslash{}bibitem\{....\}

\bibitem{key-2} these lines are what happens when I only use                 \textbackslash{}bibitem\{....\}

\bibitem[bla]{key-3} these lines are what happens when I use                 \textbackslash{}bibitem{[}bla{]}\{....\}

\bibitem[blabla]{key-4} these lines are what happens when I use                 \textbackslash{}bibitem{[}blabla{]}\{....                    \}\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}`
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add a complete example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Please be more specific: Are you getting an "ordinary" indent (first line indented, remaining lines of entry not indented) or the opposite, i.e., a "hanging" indent (first line not indented, remaining lines of entry indented)?

Comment: @Mico Neither. Please see my edit.

Comment: @IanThompson Done!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The argument of the `bibliography` environment is *not* the title of the bibliography section (as you seem to think from your code) but a string that represents the largest label in your list.  Typically this will be `9` if you have < 10 references and `99` if you have less than 100 references but more than 9.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{key-1} these lines are what happens when I only use \textbackslash{}bibitem\{....\}

\bibitem{key-2} these lines are what happens when I only use \textbackslash{}bibitem\{....\}

\bibitem[bla]{key-3} these lines are what happens when I use \textbackslash{}bibitem{[}bla{]}\{....\}

\bibitem[blabla]{key-4} these lines are what happens when I use  \textbackslash{}bibitem{[}blabla{]}\{.... \}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Ok, so putting a "9" there solves my problem. But could you please also explain **why** putting a 9 there, does ? Having played a little bit around with latex, putting any number there instead of "References" solves my problem - even if I have a "1" there and 12 entries.

Comment: @user10324 The labels are designed to align on the right bracket of the label. The number is used only as something to be measured to leave enough space for the labels as they grow.  If you use `9` and you have more than 9 references, the labels won't align properly on the right, but instead will be aligned effectively on their left brackets rather than their right brackets.