# LyX handles the bibliography environment incorrectly

Tags: bibliographies, lyx

Related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50987/dont-indent-the-bibliography) question: Does someone know, why LyX, when I create a bibliography via the "bibliography" module, inserts as the second argument the title of the bibliography section instead of a string, representing the largest label ?

So if I would like to have 12 entries in my bibliography and insert the bibliography environment via the appropriate module, by looking at the source code, Lyx inserts `\begin{thebibliography}{References}` instead of `\begin{thebibliography}{99}` as its supposed to be.  (Or at least a different number other that 99 since at the time of creating the bibliography environment LyX doesn't know yet how many entries there are in that.)

So can someone tell me how I can make LyX correctly handle the bibliography environment ? (Of course I can use "evil red code" to achieva what I want, but this is not elegant).

Comment: There is a report in LyX's bug tracker about this. It is marked as a duplicate and closed, but I cannot see a link to the bug report that it is a duplicate of ... http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/7734

Comment: Ok, weird. I also couldn't see the link. It seems that this is an bug that for some reason has got lost in the bug tracking process....Wonder how long we'll have to wait until this not-so-subtle problem is solved.

Comment: You could ask on the [mailing list](http://www.lyx.org/MailingLists). In the mean time, I guess one must use ERTs.

Comment: Lyx bug => 'too localized' for us. (We can't reasonably fix bugs in software, and don't leave things hanging open for ever.)